# How to test if ManagedObject is nil

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a question, I would like to test is my managedObject is empty then generate my CoreData.

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Adresses")
let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
AdressesProjecteurs = results as! [NSManagedObject]
print(AdressesProjecteurs)
if (AdressesProjecteurs.managedContextTmp == nil) {
  saveName()

}
```

My if condition is generating a error, so, how to test if my AdressesProjecteurs is empty ?

Thank you

Comment: *"My if condition is generating a error"* What is the error message?

Comment: Error event before compiling, count seems to be the best solution to test content of AdressesProjecteurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just don't save empty objects and then check if there IS an object saved after all

```
//check if it was NEVER saved
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Adresses")
let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
AdressesProjecteurs = results as! [NSManagedObject]
print(AdressesProjecteurs)
if (AdressesProjecteurs.count == 0) {
  saveName()
}
```